# Traversing the table with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table with the following code:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Item Description</th>
            <th>Picture URL</th>
            <th>Requested Price</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>t</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="itemsTable">
        <tr index="0">
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input id="itemName0" index="0"></td>
            <td><textarea id="itemDescription0" index="0" maxlength="200"></textarea></td>
            <td><input id="itemPicURL0" index="0"></td><td><input id="requestedPrice0" index="0"></td>
            <td><input id="category0" index="0"></td>
            <td><button class="btnRemove ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" index="0" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Remove</span></button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr index="1">
            <td>2</td>
            <td><input id="itemName1" index="1"></td>
            <td><textarea id="itemDescription1" index="1" maxlength="200"></textarea></td>
            <td><input id="itemPicURL1" index="1"></td><td><input id="requestedPrice1" index="1"></td>
            <td><input id="category1" index="1"></td>
            <td><button class="btnRemove ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" index="1" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Remove</span></button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr index="2">
            <td>3</td>
            <td><input id="itemName2" index="2"></td>
            <td><textarea id="itemDescription2" index="2" maxlength="200"></textarea></td>
            <td><input id="itemPicURL2" index="2"></td>
            <td><input id="requestedPrice2" index="2"></td>
            <td><input id="category2" index="2"></td>
            <td><button class="btnRemove ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" index="2" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Remove</span></button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to make it so if user clicks the button remove, it deletes the current row, and re-indexes all the other rows to always be from 0 to the number of rows
I can remove the row, but the re-indexing is the hard part, how do I traverse the table nodes so that I can change the indices on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btnRemove").click(function(){
   $(this).parents("tr").remove(); //this is to remove respective row
    $("table tbody#itemsTable").find("tr").each(function(i,v){
    $(this).attr("index",i); //this is to update row index
     $(this).find("td").children().attr("index",i); // this to update index for all inputs & other stuff inside td.
        $(this).find("td:first-child").text(i+1); //this is to update first td value in all rows
    });
});
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DHuee/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: it changed the index of the tr, but none of the indices of the inputs and other stuff, if you notice, each node's input has an index... how do i reach them as well ?

Comment: @LenaBru Updated my answer check once.

Answer (score 0):

just make it simple like this one,Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh007/AKcw8/1/)

```
    $(function() {
        $('.btnRemove').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        })
        $('.chckIndex').click(function(){
            alert($(this).parent().parent().index());
        })
    });
```

HTML CODE

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Item Description</th>
            <th>Picture URL</th>
            <th>Requested Price</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>t</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="itemsTable">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input id="itemName0" index="0"></td>
            <td><textarea id="itemDescription0" index="0" maxlength="200"></textarea></td>
            <td><input id="itemPicURL0" index="0"></td><td><input id="requestedPrice0" index="0"></td>
            <td><input id="category0" index="0"></td>
            <td><button class="chckIndex" index="0" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Get index</span></button></td>
            <td><button class="btnRemove ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" index="0" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Remove</span></button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td><input id="itemName1" index="1"></td>
            <td><textarea id="itemDescription1" index="1" maxlength="200"></textarea></td>
            <td><input id="itemPicURL1" index="1"></td><td><input id="requestedPrice1" index="1"></td>
            <td><input id="category1" index="1"></td>
            <td><button class="chckIndex" index="0" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Get index</span></button></td>
            <td><button class="btnRemove ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" index="1" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Remove</span></button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td><input id="itemName2" index="2"></td>
            <td><textarea id="itemDescription2" index="2" maxlength="200"></textarea></td>
            <td><input id="itemPicURL2" index="2"></td>
            <td><input id="requestedPrice2" index="2"></td>
            <td><input id="category2" index="2"></td>
            <td><button class="chckIndex" index="0" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Get index</span></button></td>
            <td><button class="btnRemove ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" index="2" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Remove</span></button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```